# Automating the creation of a formula when a new column is inserted each month

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and have a spreadsheet that is modified with new data each month by inserting a column, then Month over Month and Year over Year must be recalculated by adjusting the formula to the new month to the previous month and the previous year's same month. I assume that I need to use ReferTo or RefersToR1C1 to get the cell references in a string data type to make this happen. However, I do not know enough to code this and have spent a day trying to find examples with no luck. If someone could point me in the right direction to research this I will do the work or if someone has a similar example I am sure I could adjust it. Any help would be appreciated.
Tried to use a Excel worksheet function that I was familiar with, but VBA doesn't appreciate mixing up VBA with EXCEL functions, so that is why I am thinking I need RefersTo or RefersToR1C1. Here is where I am at.

```
Sub MonthYearProc()
    Dim CurrentMoYr As Date
    Dim CurrentMo As Integer
    Dim CurrentYr As Integer
    Dim UserMoYr As Date
    Dim UserMo As Integer
    Dim UserYr As Integer
    Dim NewMoYr As String
    Dim CurntMOCell As String
    Dim LstMoCell As String
    Dim LstYrMoCell As String
    Dim MoMPercnt As String
    Dim YoYPercnt As String
    Dim MoMCol As Integer
    Dim YoYCol As Integer
    Dim CrntMoCol As Integer
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Activate
    CurrentMoYr = ActiveCell.Value
    CurrentMo = Month(CurrentMoYr)
    CurrentYr = Year(CurrentMoYr)
    UserMo = InputBox("What Month are we processing? {Enter an Integer}", CurrentMo)
    UserYr = InputBox("What Year is related to the Month being processed?", CurrentYr)

'if statement that determines new month and new fiscal year & modifies formula for new data
    
    If UserMo <> CurrentMo Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
        Selection.EntireColumn.Insert
        NewMoYr = UserMo & "/" & "1" & "/" & UserYr
        CurrentMoYr = DateValue(NewMoYr)
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = CurrentMoYr
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
        CrntMoCol = ActiveCell.Column
        MoMCol = CrntMoCol + 1
        YoYCol = CrntMoCol + 2
        CurntMOCell = Application.WorksheetFunction.Address(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column)
        LstMoCell = Application.WorksheetFunction.Address(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Offset(CrntMoCol - 1).Select)
        LstYrMoCell = Application.WorksheetFunction.Address(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Offset(CrntMoCol - 12).Select)
        MoMPercnt = CurntMOCell & "-" & LstMoCell & "/" & LstMoCell
        YoYPercnt = CurntMOCell & "-" & LstYrMoCell & "/" & LstYrMoCell
        Cells(2, MoMCol).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=" & MoMPercnt
        Cells(2, YoYCol).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=" & YoYPercnt
        Range(Cells(2, MoMCol), Cells(2, YoYCol)).Copy
        Range(Cells(3, MoMCol), Cells(33, YoYCol)).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        NewFYFlag = False
    End If
    
    If UserMo = CurrentMo Then
        MsgBox ("Month is the same")
    End If

' Test for Fiscal Year Change

    If UserMo = 10 Then
        NewFYFlag = True
    End If
        
End Sub
```

Comment: It might be easier to just modify the formula you're using. Maybe you could provide a screenshot or the current formula you're using for Month over Month and Year over Year?

Comment: FYI `Application.WorksheetFunction.Address(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column)` is the same as `ActiveCell.Address()`

Comment: I know that it is easier for me just to edit the formula and copy in EXCEL It takes almost 10 biz days to get the input from the person receiving the data in EXCEL reports.  Formula: It is the first row. there are 33 rows that need the same formula:
=(AB2-AA2)/AB2 'month over month
=(AB2-P2)/P2   'year over year
however, when you insert a column at AC then the formula is still referring to the previous month as the current month and I was trying to keep the end-user from having to to enter the formula
=(AC2-AB2)/AB2 'for month over month and 
=(AC2-Q2)/Q2   'for year over year

Comment: I found my answer from  
Darren Bartrup-Cook
 Jul 4, 2018 at 11:03
If you place in a function you can use as a worksheetfunction as well - 
Public Function GetMyAddress(Cell_Ref As Range) As String: GetMyAddress = Cell_Ref.Address: End Function.
Then I used this function to pass the Cell Reference to the formula. Still working on it though since the cell reference is still off a bit.